# Check all inputs of a class and uncheck other class when any is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, input

my issue is the following, I have two classes of inputs : c1s and c1n.

I want that if any input of the class c1n is checked all the items from the class c1s become checked  and the items from c1n unchecked.

I have done the following, but still doesnt work, for example the input that is clicked wont change and the rest yes, and some other weird cases... Maybe someone can see my code and offer a simpler solution.

The code below is thought for swaping the inputs of c1s to checked and c1n to unchcecked:

It will first take the closest c1s item class clicked, make an array for inputs c1s and c1n, for eaceh c1s set property checked if its not checked, and for each c1n set property checked to false.

```js
$('#TablaAcciones').on('click', '.c1s', function() {
    console.log(".");
    var inputsc1s = $(".c1s");
    var inputsc1n = $(".c1n");
    var val = $(this).closest('.c1s').first().attr("value");
    alert("s" + val);
    inputsc1s.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
    inputsc1n.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TablaAcciones">
    <thead>
        <tr>Hello</tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>c1s</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="row1" class="c1s" checked="checked" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>c1n</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="row1" class="c1n" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>c1s</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" class="c1s" name="row2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>c1n</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" class="c1n" checked="checked" name="row2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code is working 50/50 but I legit can't come up with a final solution.

**FIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ggs8zvkj/

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you build an example on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: We'd like to see a [mcve] with all of the relevant code in the question itself, as indicated in [ask].

Comment: Uploaded fiddle for swithcing for marking all the unmarkeds c1s and unmark the c1n

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. For each row your `.c1s` and `.c1n` have the same `name` attribute, which means only one of them can be checked. Yet, when you check on `.c1s`, you want to check `.c1n`? That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: what in case if checked from .c1n class

Comment: For this each row only one value can be used, if any input from the class c1X is marked all of those input must take the very same value, while the other class c1Y must uncheck.

Comment: Please start debugging with `console.log` instead of `alert()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This'll check all the c1s & uncheck c1n.
As you are using class you dont need to use each if you change the property of class it'll reflect all the element have that class.
e.g. `$(".c1s").prop("checked", true)` this'll set true for all element have c1s

```js
 $('#TablaAcciones').on('click', '.c1s', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(".c1s").prop("checked", true);
            $(".c1n").prop("checked", false);
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TablaAcciones">
    <thead>
        <tr>Hello</tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>c1s</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="row1" class="c1s" checked="checked" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>c1n</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="row1" class="c1n" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>c1s</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" class="c1s" name="row2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>c1n</label>
            <input type="radio" value="1" class="c1n" checked="checked" name="row2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Man this worked like a charm... I was over complicating myself, I can't thank you enough!